# Prometheus Error - context deadline exceeded

Tags: wmi, prometheus, grafana

I have multiple targets for my prometheus server but only for one I am getting the error

**context deadline exceeded**

Even I am able to browse the metrics URL from wmi_exporter and it just results in less a second, I tried increasing the scrape interval for this specific target but no luck.

I cannot understand if I am able to browser the wmi_exporter URL from the same machine where prometheus is running, why prometheus is still showing that error.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very easy, you only need to edit the **YAML** file of daemon set `prometheus-node-exporter` to delete `hostNetwork: true`. If you are using Helm chart prometheus-operator to install Prometheus Operator, you can override the `hostNetwork` setting using a values file with `-f` option.

```
prometheus-node-exporter:
  hostNetwork: false
```

Comment: I have some doubts, will it work for wmi exporter as well and also do I need to update the file in which I have defined targets?

Comment: You can once try with above approach if not working then we will discuss further.

Comment: Atleast let me know which file you are talking about and if it;s prometheus.yml then under which section I should add this

Comment: you only need to edit the YAML file of daemon set prometheus-node-exporter I also mentioned in my answer you can export anywhere in that file.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, I am using WMI EXPORTER for Windows Server, Daemon Set seems to be a word from Kubernetes world

Comment: Please check this article for the ref:- https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1438